# header('Location: /'); giving virtualhost location

Tags: php, apache2, virtualhost

I'm developing a system where users need to make an account, and once the account is fully created it should take them to the home page, for this I use the PHP tag `header`.

My code looks like this:

```
private function redirect($location) {
   if(!isset($location)) { $location = '/'; }
   header('Location: ' . $location);
}
```

For some reason when I execute this without specifying `$location` or with anything it's taking me to (in the url bar)

```
/var/www/html/our-site-name/<$location>
```

Does anyone know what might be the issue here?

Comment: `'Location:  http://www.example.com'`

Comment: Are you sure $location is not set before if statement?

Comment: @DmitriyTroyan Yeah. I just tried a normal header('Location: /') and it did the same thing

Answer (score 0):

say you have a directory structure like this

```
<wwwroot>
    <login>
    <signup>    
    index.php
```

then your function should look like this if it is run from the signup folder

```
private function redirect($location) {
      if(!isset($location)) { $location = './index.php'; }
   header('Location:'.$location);
}
```

"./" takes you up 1 directory